# Скрытие полей от определенного пользователя

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field

Есть несколько полей c различными значениями. Как можно сделать так, чтобы пользователь видел только некоторые из них? Например, администратор может видеть поля только значения "DoorAcc1", Customer видит только значения "DoorAcc2".

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-has_field_rules="no" data-is_pricing_rules="yes" class="wccpf-field " name="options[]" value="DoorAcc1" wccpf-type="checkbox" wccpf-pattern="mandatory" wccpf-mandatory="no">

<input type="checkbox" data-has_field_rules="no" data-is_pricing_rules="yes" class="wccpf-field " name="options[]" value="DoorAcc2" wccpf-type="checkbox" wccpf-pattern="mandatory" wccpf-mandatory="no">


<input type="checkbox" data-has_field_rules="no" data-is_pricing_rules="yes" class="wccpf-field " name="options[]" value="DoorAcc3" wccpf-type="checkbox" wccpf-pattern="mandatory" wccpf-mandatory="no">
```

Comment: Проверить пользователя на принадлежность к определенной группе, в зависимости от этого выводить нужную инфу.

Comment: С принадлежностью к группе нет проблем, а вот как вывести по значению не могу понять

Comment: <?php $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; if('192.168.1.1'=$ip){ echo '<input type="checkbox" data-has_field_rules="no" data-is_pricing_rules="yes" class="wccpf-field " name="options[]" value="DoorAcc2" wccpf-type="checkbox" wccpf-pattern="mandatory" wccpf-mandatory="no">'; ?> 2ой чекбокс виден

Comment: или пользователь если керберос аутонтификация, ну или по логину, админку создаёш вписываешь, если то видно, или иначе else

Comment: Вышло как было, ничего не изменилось. Что-то не так?
<?php if ( current_user_can( 'remises_5' ) )
    echo '<input type="checkbox" data-has_field_rules="no" data-is_pricing_rules="yes" class="wccpf-field " name="options[]" value="Ferme porte 15%" wccpf-type="checkbox" wccpf-pattern="mandatory" wccpf-mandatory="no">';?>

Comment: remises_5 - роль, для которой нужно отображение поля со значением Ferme porte 15%

Comment: ) ){...........   }

Answer (score 0):

если получение роли пользователя - не проблема, то

```
<?php 
switch ($userRole) {
    case 'admin':
        $value[1] = 'DoorAcc1';        
        $value[2] = '';
        $value[3] = '';
        break;
    case 'cusromer':
        $value[1] = '';        
        $value[2] = 'DoorAcc2';
        $value[3] = '';
        break;
    default:
        $value[1] = 'DoorAcc1';        
        $value[2] = 'DoorAcc2';
        $value[3] = 'DoorAcc3';
        break;
} 

//тут генерируем форму удобным способом, например

foreach ($value as $v) {
    inputWithValue($v);
}
```

если нужно просто показать какие-то части формы в зависимости от роли, то в .phtml шаблоне нужно сделать что-то типа

```
<form>
<?php 
if ($role == 'admin') {
    ?>
    <!-- поле видимое только для админа -->
    <input type="checkbox"  name="options[]" value="DoorAcc1" >
    <?php
}
if ($role == 'customer') {
    ?>
    <!-- поле видимое только для пользователя -->
    <input type="checkbox"  name="options[]" value="DoorAcc2" >
    <?php
}
?>
<!-- поле видимое только для всех -->
    <input type="checkbox"  name="options[]" value="DoorAcc2" >
    <submit></submit>
</form>
```